# C# convert "double" to "ushort"

Tags: c#, double, converters, ushort

I'm stuck with variables format. I know this is a stupid question but I'm on it for 2 hours and I'm losing my mind.

The problem is:

I have:

```
command.Data = new ushort[] { xx, yy, zz };
```

And I need to do:

```
ushort zz = System.Math.Tan(c1AngleX);
```

But the output of System.Math.Tan is "double", so I kinda can't have the "ushort" there.

I tried this

```
ushort zz = (Convert.ToUInt16 (System.Math.Tan(c1AngleX));
```

But it does not work. (Cannot convert "double" to "string")

There's any way to convert "double" to "ushort"?

(I'm sorry if this question is "too trivial", but I'm really stuck)

Comment: If you convert the results of `System.Math.Tan(c1AngleX)` to `ushort` you will have data loss.

Comment: Your way to convert the double to ushort is corret but that leads to data loss.

Comment: There's no such error: "it does not work". Please be more specific.

Comment: "...throws a `System.ItDoesNotWorkException` with message..."

Comment: Start by avoiding `ushort`. It should be a rarity.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ushort` but for future you do have `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`.  But as noted `ushort` will cause data loss.

Comment: @Greg: the parse methods are suitable for strings only

Comment: I understand now that I will lose data, that's something I have to think about. thank you.
I need Ushort because command.data only accepts ushort.

Comment: @JeffRSon Then use `Convert.ToDouble`, the point was there a ways to push to a `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ushort is a 16-bit variable that can hold whole values between 0 and 65535. 
A double is a 8-byte variable that can hold .. lots of values, including fractions.

So if you convert the double to a ushort you will probably lose data. This is why the system will not let you do it without explicit instruction.

The easiest way to cast is using the cast operators: eg

```
double d = 99.99;
ushort u = (ushort)d;
```

or you can cast it using one of the maths functions that explicitly round or truncate the double, but they return doubles so you'll still have to cast.

You should consider why you want to put a double value into a ushort type first. Designing for correct behaviour is far more important than squishing a round peg into a square hold just because you can.

Comment: i recommend Convert.ToUInt16 rather than a cast. I had a case where `(ushort)(0.57*100)` gave the incorrect result **56**. Using `Convert.ToUInt16(0.57*100)` correctly returned **57**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you seem to have is the fact that converting from a floating point type to an interger type will lose you the decimals.

If you do your conversion on the value `0.111333423` (let's assume that is the result of Tan) `zz` will have the value `0` because any decimals will be removed. And since `ushort` is also unsigned, the sign isn't transferred either.

There are ways to deal with decimals in integer types called fixed-point integer, for instance. But that is assuming that you really need to use ushort (or any integer type for that matter) for what ever reason. In case of such functions, you should avoid integer types due to data loss.

Comment: It's not only the decimals. It's also the sign that may not fit `ushort`.

Comment: @JeffRSon thanks, I forgot about the unsigned part. Added it to my answer.

Comment: Well, due to the sign the result may be completely wrong. Try it with `(ushort)` cast and an argument of 1.9. It will result in 65534. `Convert.ToUnit16` will throw an `OverflowException`

Comment: @JeffRSon What are you talking about?  If you explicitly cast a double with a value of 1.9 to ushort you get 1, not 65534.

Comment: @juharr: Talking about System.Math.Tan.